# FlashDevelop Profiler Not showing anything

Tags: actionscript-3, profiler, flashdevelop

Trying to solve Memory Leak problem ... and I am using Flash Develop ..  And I clicked start profiler before compile the code.. but still I am not able too see anything .. It was working fine 2 days back!
Can anyone help me regarding this ..

Comment: You will get a better respone on FlashDevelop.org forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the clock icon button on the tool bar up top 
Make sure the flag is green in the pop up window that you get from clicking on the clock icon.
Run your app it should be working now